# function not declared in scope vs. multiple definitions of function

Tags: function, include, scope

I'm using Code::Blocks to make a simple game.  I'm trying to learn how to keep good file structure, but I'm clearly missing something because I can't seem to call a program-scope function from an object that is defined in a .cpp file.

So, I have an object, tank, which is declared in a header file, include/tank.h, and which is defined in a .cpp file, src/tank.cpp (these are the files that Code::Blocks made for me when I used the file->new->class menu).  I also have a header file for the function apply_image(), called apply.h.   apply.h is included in the main.cpp file.

When src/tank.cpp looks like this:

```
#include "tank.h"

void tank::drawMe(SDL_Surface* screen)
{
    apply_surface(x,y, tankImg, screen);
}
```

I get a compiler error that reads |error: ‘apply_surface’ was not declared in this scope|
So I add an #include for "apply.h", like so:

```
#include "tank.h"
#include "apply.h"

void tank::drawMe(SDL_Surface* screen)
{
    apply_surface(x,y, tankImg, screen);
}
```

and now I get a compiler error that reads |multiple definition of `apply_surface(int, int, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*)'|   I can't win!

I've consulted a few texts on C++, but I can't see what I'm doing differently.   Any clarification is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323290/c-multiple-definitions)

Comment: thanks!  I added `extern void apply_surface(int, int, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Surface*);` to my first code snippet and it works fine!  Thank you very much!